# Powerpc systemsim-p8 does not boot debian 64 in ubuntu 64 16.04 LTS

Tags: powerpc

I am trying to boot a debian ppc power8 ( or 7 ) in a simulation. 
I followed the instructions in [1].

The only thing I manage to boot is an ram drive ( initrd ) with mambo kernel, but it is a closed source. I can't do much with it. 
So , now I try to boot a mambo kernel ( with a bigus disk support ) from [2] with the debian image disk from [1].

The kernel manages to mount the drive, but i do not reach a login as depiced in [3].

[1] https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/set2/sas/f/pwrfs/pwrfsinstall.html.

[2] https://github.com/rpsene/linux.git

[3]

```
9415446: (688292884): [^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Reached target Local File Systems.
729612844: (688490282):          Starting LSB: Raise network interfaces....
730353740: (689231178):          Starting Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage...
731308417: (690185857):          Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
736470477: (695348428): udev-finish (1378) used greatest stack depth: 10752 bytes left
753931943: (712810985): [^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Copy rules generated while the root was ro.
765419589: (724298838): [^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
804041342: (762920770): [^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
804330683: (763210111):          Starting Update UTMP about System Reboot/Shutdown...
815762188: (774642735): [^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Update UTMP about System Reboot/Shutdown.
817676182: (776556815): systemd-journald[1213]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
1076627432: (1035512412): [^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
```

Comment: Does the kernel/initrd work with qemu-system-ppc64? Its a bit ambiguous if you are talking about debian or ubuntu. Why have you chosen this kernel tree?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this one https://github.com/open-power-sdk/power-simulator? This is the version I have uploaded last year. (bug report are welcome).

Also, you can get free Power VMs at https://minicloud.parqtec.unicamp.br/minicloud/

```
I have got the simulator up and running: 
https://pastebin.com/ibGPeEFu

cloudusr@mambo:~$ ssh root@172.19.98.109
The authenticity of host '172.19.98.109 (172.19.98.109)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:x4/jPYq6SggOeSPOlQaxJlucih6elJLqog+i4P/euxY.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '172.19.98.109' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@172.19.98.109's password:

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
root@debianle:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
cpu     : POWER9 (raw), altivec supported
clock       : 2000.000000MHz
revision    : 2.0 (pvr 004e 0200)

timebase    : 512000000
platform    : PowerNV
model       : Mambo,Simulated-System
machine     : PowerNV Mambo,Simulated-System
firmware    : OPAL
```

Comment: raz@localhost:~/power-simulator$ ./dev install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
ImportError: No module named req
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
ImportError: No module named req
[sudo] password for raz: 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.

Comment: Try running as root, sudo -i.

Answer (score 0):

I've booted systemsim a bunch of times with ubuntu userspace. Do you have a copy of the disk image somewhere I can try? Is the sim userspace LE or BE?